# "Log in with Twitter" Web Site Integration Question

Tags: asp-classic, oauth, twitter, twitter-oauth

I've got classic ASP site and I'm trying to integrate the ["Sign in with Twitter"](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/sign_in_with_twitter) functionality. I've followed the example [here](http://scottdesapio.com/VBScriptOAuth/) and I've got the button working to sign into twitter but what I've been asked to do is this...

If a user has an account with our website and previously signed into twitter via our website then going forward, when the user visits our site and they are signed into twitter then they are automatically signed into our site as well. This goes on forever as long as the user doesn't revoke our website's permissions from their twitter account (done by going to twitter and accessing their settings).

I know I can store the access token provided when the user first logs into twitter from our site with their user record in our website's database but that doesn't do me much good if the user is coming to our site because I won't be able to know what user is visiting to pull the access token from our database.

I hope that makes enough sense for someone to help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the same procedure as if the user log in with your credentials: **Store a piece of information** (the encripted userID or a Session token) about the user **in a cookie** and then try to restore the information from the cookie.